# fullcalendar: Detect if in weekview?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to add a button to my fullcalendar's header that will only show when in weekview.

I'm unsure how to detect if the calendar is currently in weekview though.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

The purpose is that I need users to be able to click a button to identify that they are done entering their events for that week.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getView' ).name` - this should return your view

see more informations here:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/getView/

Answer (score 0):

add `viewRender` callback,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  ...
  viewRender: function(view, element){
    if(view.name.indexOf('Week') != -1) {
      // add button to header left
      $('.fc-header-left').append('<span class="fc-header-space"></span><span class="fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">Button</span>');
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer too.  Really appreciate the code for the button in the header too

Comment: You're welcome, but I still think my answer is better than @HellBaby and right on your question. See more here, http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/